# Как проверить наличие цифр в input регулярным выражением?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо проверить с помощью регулярного выражения, введены ли в поле input цифры или нет, если нет - выдавать алерт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function isNumeric( value ) {
  return (/^[\d]+$/g).test( value );
}

// ну и потом что-то типа
if( !isNumeric(input.value) ) {
  // введены не только цифры
}
```

Comment: как всегда, ты меня выручаешь) спасибо!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста =)